# discord.js args not being pushed into array

Tags: javascript, discord.js

made this code that should add an arg to an array:

```
// Ban Words and Variables
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const multipleArgs = args.slice(0).join(" ");
const banWords = [];

if (banWords.some((word) => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send("don't say that!");
} else if (command === "banword") {
  banWords.push(multipleArgs);
  message.channel.send("Ban word added");
  console.log("Array updated");
}
```

but the command doesn't seem to add the arg to the array even if it logs "array updated" and "ban word added". Btw the command is in the main index.js

Comment: Are you sure `args` contains a value when declaring `multipleArgs`?
Note that the (mutable) `shift` operation in the `command` variable modifies the array.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `Array#shift()` mutates the array to only include the first element, all other elements are discarded